# When is an extension of characters de Rham? 

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations, reference-request

Let $G$ be the abolute Galois group of $\mathbb Q_p$, let $\delta_1, \delta_2: G\rightarrow L^{\times}$ be continuous characters, where $L$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$.  Assume that $\delta_1\delta_2^{-1}$ is neither trivial nor the cyclotomic character then 
$Ext^1_{G}(\delta_2, \delta_1)$ is one dimensional. Hence there exists a unique non-split extension:

$0\rightarrow \delta_1\rightarrow V\rightarrow \delta_2\rightarrow 0$.

When is $V$ de Rham?

I believe that the answer is if and only if  both $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ are de Rham and the Hodge-Tate weight of $\delta_1\delta_2^{-1}$ is $\ge 1$ (at least if the Hodge-Tate weights of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ are distinct) and I guess I could x it out  by using Bloch-Kato's paper in Grothendieck Festschrift, bu the answer must be well 
known and maybe even written down somewhere.

Ideally, I would like to be able to quote a reference, where this has been worked out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dear Vytas,

lemma 6.5 of my 2002 inventiones paper says that if $V$ is any de Rham representation all of whose HT weights are at least 1, then any extension of $Q_p$ by $V$ is itself de Rham. This holds for reps of $G_K$ where the residue field $k$ of $K$ can be any perfect field (not merely finite).

If $k$ is finite, then this was well-known before and follows from the results of Bloch and Kato (which I think you should quote). See proposition 1.28 of Nekovar's "On $p$-adic height pairings" where this is stated explicitly and proved using BK's computations.

EDIT: see also the "Proposition" on page 196 of Perrin-Riou's "Représentations $p$-adiques ordinaires". It predates Nekovar's paper, and although the result is less strong, it's enough for what you need.

Answer (score 6):

Dear Vytas,

Twisting by $\delta_1^{-1}$, we may restrict attention to non-split extensions 
$$0 \to 1 \to V \to \delta \to 0,$$ and of course we may assume that $\delta$ 
is de Rham.
If the HT wt. of $\delta$ is $\geq 0$, such a non-trivial extension is never de Rham,
while
if the HT wt. of $\delta$ is $< 0$, such a non-trivial extension is always de Rham
(assuming as you do that $\delta$ is neither trivial nor inverse cyclotomic).

A statement of these facts is incorporated into the statement of Prop. 4.4.4 of [my Coates paper](http://wwww.math.northwestern.edu/~emerton/pdffiles/coates.pdf), but the statement is
standard, and follows e.g. from a theorem of Hyodo, stating that
a de Rham ext. of pst. reps. is in fact pst.  (Of course this follows
from the more general statement that de Rham implies pst., but is easier.  I don't know
the original reference,
but see e.g. Thm. 4.5.4 and Cor. 4.5.9 of [my never-quite-finished paper on crystalline extensions with Mark Kisin](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~emerton/dvifiles/ext.dvi).)

In any event,
knowing that one has only has to check whether the extension is pst. (either by Hyodo or by the more general equivalence of de Rham and pst), a simple and direct calculation with pst. Dieudonne modules gives what is required.

I'm sorry I can't just give you a clean reference.

Best wishes,

Matt

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at section 16 of this document of Laurent Berger : http://www.umpa.ens-lyon.fr/~lberger/barcelone/BergerBarcelone.pdf